# Reply to specific socket client

Tags: c#, sockets, c#-2.0

I am using C#.
   I have one socket server in PC A and three socket clients in PC B,PC C,and PC D.When PC A receives data, I want to send this data to either PC B or PC C or PC D. I mean i don't want to send this data to all PC.I just want to send the PC i need to send. Now, when server receives data from one client PC, it sends back to all clients PC. Thank you.

Comment: show us your code attempt....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data that PC A receives needs to include information about which client(s) it should be passed on to.  PC A can then look at which clients are currently connected to it and forward the data as needed.